# Conventional place to store files used by Clojure (or JVM) apps

Tags: java, file, clojure, jvm, leiningen

I have an application written in Clojure. This application is helping write other applications (e.g., as a plugin for `leiningen`). To do so, it needs a place to write some files, which are used more-or-less internally and don't really have to be thrown in the face of the user (no need to hide them from her, though).

I've been using [`clojure.java.io/resource`](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.java.io-api.html#clojure.java.io/resource) for something like that, but it seems that it allows only to access resources bundled with the application, but not create new resources or modify existing ones.

I'm considering just using something like `~/.myapp/` for that, but I suspect `Clojure`, or `Java`, or `Leiningen` have some convention about that, with API and everything, to save me some trouble. However, as I'm a newbie in this, I have no idea where to dig.

As I said it's a plugin for `leiningen` but I can't really use `%project/out/` folder or something like that because I want it to be able to run even without a project.

Comment: `~/.myapp/` would be per-user, not system-wide. Could you clarify the intent?

Comment: I don't really have an opinion about that. Probably user-wide is the better option especially since it won't require any special rights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's a subdirectory under `~/.lein` you can use, probably something like `~/.lein/plugin-name/your_stuff_here`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is no single ultimately accepted convention on where to put intermediate files for programs, neither in java/clojure world nor in native world. However, I guess, there are some basic principles present.

As far as I know, most programs separate all files they need into distribution files (the ones which should not be modified: resources like icons and sounds or binaries like jar files), configuration files (the ones which user can modify, either directly or through the program itself) and temporary files (I guess it is obvious what are they).

Distribution files are usually installed via package manager (mostly on linux systems) or, if necessary, they are installed manually in some predefined directory, like `/opt`. On Windows systems these are installed usually by the installation program. These files are not subject to change directly but can usually be updated by package manager on upgrades.

Configuration files are usually stored in user home directory (if the program is user application). It is sad, but there are no convention whatsoever on where to put these files exactly. It is a pain on unix systems (`~` cluttering), but on Windows IMO it is even worse because files can end up virtually anywhere in the filesystems since it is not widely accepted to configure restrictive rights on filesystems under Windows.

However, currently there seem to be a tendency (in linux world at least) to store configuration files in subdirectories of `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` environment variable; this variable usually resolves to `~/.config` path. I'm sure that it is right to use this directory for configuration. There is a family of these variables (`$XDG_{CONFIG,CACHE,DATA}_HOME`), each one used for certain kind of files. I think this is freedesktop standard. I don't know whether Windows has something like this, but it is highly possible; I would have tried to find some info on this and used it if I had such need.

Many programs allow to set exact location of configuration directory explicitly, e.g. IntelliJ IDEA IDE. This also can be an option.

Temporary files are usually stored to a directory the system provides for temporary files. Under unix systems it is usually `/tmp`, under Windows it can be e.g. `C:\Users\%USER%\AppData\Local\Temp`. In Java you can get temporary directory location using system properties. In Clojure it will look like

```
(System/getProperty "java.io.tmpdir")
```

If I recall correctly, there is even a function somewhere in clojure standard library which allows you to get this value.

Only really temporary files should be stored there since this directory can be cleared (in recent linux distributions it is even stored in RAM).

**TL;DR**

If you want to store persistent user-wide configuration (work, cache etc) files, use `~/.config` directory under unix systems and some sane directory under Windows (more googling is required on this); if you want to store temporary files which you won't need after you do some piece of work in the program, use standard system temporary directory which you can get via `"java.io.tmpdir"` system property.

Comment: Thank you! My files are somewhere between `temporary` and `configuration` in your distinction: they are something like a cache which is really nice to have ready, but no problem to lose. So I'm not sure about using `/tmp`.

Comment: (By the way, I went with the suggestion from the accepted answer, useful only for `lein` plugins. But thank you for the very good answer!)

Comment: There is widely used `~/.cache` directory for cache, it is in fact `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`. Most browsers use it for storing cache. Glad that you liked it)